# Assembly x64 Get user input string into integer for comparing

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm, x86-64

I am trying to create a program that will ask for 2 numbers and then compare them. I originally just compared the two user inputted strings but found out that it does not work. It treats them as strings and not actual characters. So if I were to do the following:

```
N1: 0000001
N2: 20
N1 is larger than N2
```

So I was told by a co-worker to convert the numbers to the ordinal values. I have this code so far..

```
r10 = length of inp1
xor rcx, rcx
ord:
    cmp r10, rcx                    ;compare length against counter
    je error                        ;jmp 
    movzx r14, BYTE[inp1+rcx]       ;store first char from inp1 to r14
    cmp r14, 0x0a                   ;compare first char against /n
    je error                        ;jmp if /n
    mov rax, 10                     ;mov 10 into rax
    mul r15                         ;mul rax * r15
    add r15, rax                    ;add rax to r15        
    sub r14, 30                     ;sub 30 from r14
    add r15, r13                    ;add r13 to r15
    inc rcx                         ;inc counter
    jmp ord                         ;loop
```

This is based off the C code that is:

```
char str[6] = "1234\n";
int i = 0;
int tmp = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    if (str[i] != '\n') {
        tmp *= 10;
        tmp += str[i];
        i++;
    }
}
```

My output is not correct. I am not sure what I am missing here. He walked through the C code showing each step of how int i and int tmp change and end up working out, but with my ASM I can't get it to do the same.

I am compiling with

```
nasm -f elf64 -o out.o out.asm && gcc -o out out.o
```

Comment: Co-worker or your professor. If it was a coworker they should be telling you to code it in _C_ and let the optimizer do the work.

Comment: Annotate what you expect each register to contain at the start and end of each instruction, and verify that the instruction you execute correctly transforms the starting condition to the ending condition. It's not clear what `r14` and `r15` are supposed to be, so we can't really say what's wrong.

Comment: @RaymondChen r14 is just the current character in the array, r15 is the accumulated result so far (`tmp`). What i don't see is where R15 is initialized to 0.

Comment: I'd recommend learning to use the debugging (`gdb`) to step through the  code and watch the registers and memory as the code executes. You should be able to find out why it fails.

Comment: You'd probably discover this line is a problem `sub r14, 30`. That is 30 decimal. You want 0x30 (hex) or even better just use `sub r14, '0'` . This line looks wrong `add r15, r13` . R13 seems like it should be R14

Comment: R15 += R15 * 10 means R15 *= 11.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I was hoping OP would explain what the registers mean. Because that would lead to the realization that they aren't being used as intended. (For example, what's up with `r13`?)

Comment: Why do so many people use the inconvenient one-operand `mul`  which doesn't work with immediate operands? (and which spends extra time putting the high half of the result in `rdx`?)  x86 since 386 has `imul eax, r15d, 10` which is fantastically convenient (one of x86's very few 3-operand integer instructions, with 2 sources + a separate destination), or you can use LEA twice for lower latency than `imul`+`add`.

Comment: You can still compare just strings... you must skip leading zeroes, and compare length of strings from non-zero digit first, the longer one is bigger, if they have the same length, then you can compare them lexicographically (i.e. until the first char difference, and the bigger char means bigger number). If no difference is found, they represent the same value. This works only when you allow only the same input value formatting, i.e. decimal integers (would not work for cases like "1000" vs "1e5", or hexa vs binary, etc). (would be probably abuse of original task, but at least requires skill)